# Error while trying to connect MySQL and Gogs containers with docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, gogs

On this screens you can see the error that I have

[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dXc7.png)
[screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWZcd.png)

### This is my docker-compose.yml

```
 version: '3'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ~/workspace/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=soextreme
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root

  gogs:
      image: gogs/gogs:latest
      depends_on:
        - mysql
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 3000:3000
        - "10022:22"
      volumes:
        - ~/workspace/gogs:/data
```

---

---

For note, I found this solution on this link : [my docker compose file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668793/docker-gogs-connection-is-refused-by-mysql-container)
but it's not working for me,
Can you please help me, Thank you.

Comment: I have the same error, and it it not the same issue than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668793/docker-gogs-connection-is-refused-by-mysql-container as we are having "this authentication plugin is not supported" it is more related to https://github.com/gogits/gogs/issues/5187 but I could not resolve it

Answer (score 1):

I could make it work with following procedure :

On the mysql Docker, edit the file :

> /etc/mysql/my.cnf

and add the line :

```
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

then connect as root on the mysql database :

```
mysql -hdb -P3306 -uroot -p
```

and execute following statement :

```
alter user 'gogs'@'%' identified with mysql_native_password by '...'
```

You can see current configuration with query :

```
select User, plugin from mysql.user;
```

On gogs, in the database host :

> db:3306

and the connection worked for me.

It may not be necessary to modify authentication plugin in the configuration file once gogs plugin is modified, see by yourself.